# What BF4 shortcuts have been released?

Tags: battlefield-4, origin

What shortcuts have been released? I'm going to be mad if I missed one but I just got the handgun shortcut today off of Origin. I'm a premium player.

Answer (score 2):

According to the news section of Battlelog, the hand gun and DMR shortcut kits have been released as of Februrary 18th, and are available until the 25th.  You must have premium for the DMR shortcut kit.

See below for the timing:

> Battlefield 4 Premium members will get access to two special Shortcut
>   Kits, on top of two other Shortcut Kits accessible to all Battlefield
>   4 owners. See below for the handout schedule.
>
> **February 18 to February 24:**
>    Shortcut Kit: Hand Guns
>    Battlefield 4 Premium Shortcut Kit: DMR’s
>
> **February 25 to March 4:**
>   Shortcut Kit: Grenades
>   Battlefield 4 Premium Shortcut Kit: Shotguns

Date emphasis added by me.  See the [source](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/news/view/shortcut-kits-now-live/) for details on how to claim the shortcut kits.

Answer (score 0):

DMR shortcut and pistols shortcut are available right now, and until the end of the week.

DICE talked about a grenade shortcut and a shotgun shortcut, but I didn t found much information.

EDIT:

Grenade and shotgun shortcut will be available next week, keep in mind that shotgun and dmr shortcut are Premium exclusives.

Answer (score -1):

Pistols and dmgs free to premium. That's it till the 24th.